# Only one QLineEdit works in Qt Browser

Tags: c++, qt, browser, qlineedit

I cross compiled Qt Browser application(qt-everywhere 4.7.2 example code). Browser on the target allows keyboard input only to the first `lineEdit`. I have a login page in the Qt browser in which,I need to give username and password.I could type Username but `lineEdit` for password has the cursor blinking but it does not take any keyboard input.

Comment: It would help if you said in which platform that occurs. Also, is it possible that you are actually writing something, but the `lineEdit` does not show it because it's a _password_ field? In other words, have you checked the contents of the password field _after_ submitting the form?

Comment: @Joum Am using connectcore wi-imx51 with linux.Even if the lineEdit doesn't anything still the cursor should move to next position but that doesnt happen.The cursor will be blinking at the first character place only